# What's the difference between Boundedness Theorem and Extreme Value Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima, extreme-value-theorem

I know that the Boundedness Theorem states that if a function is continuous on a closed interval then it is bounded on that interval, but doesn't it mean that it also attains the maximum and minimum values? How can a function be bounded on a interval, but at the same time not attain the maximum and minimum?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Did you mean $\sin(\arctan x)$?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio, but the Boundedness Theorem and the Extreme Value Theorem both need the function to be defined on a closed interval right?

Comment: @AdamMazur No: take $f(x)=x$, defined on the closed interval $(-\infty, \infty)$.  The interval needs to be compact.  Now consider a continuous function, defined on a compact interval.  The image of that compact interval is compact as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take, for instance, $f\colon[-1,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x\in(-1,1)\\0&\text{ if }x=\pm1,\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is bounded, but it doesn't attain a maximum or a minimum.

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful.

Comment: Did you consider the possibility of accepting my answer?

Comment: Is this Continuous : at +1 & -1 ?

Comment: @Prem No, it is not. There is no continuous counterexample due to the Extreme Value Theorem.

Comment: Question says "The boundedness theorem says that if a function f(x) is **continuous** on a closed interval [a,b], then it is bounded on that interval" ; This answer uses Discontinuous functions. I am not sure this is answering that question.

Comment: @Prem The person who asked the question has accepted my answer. Besides the question “How can a function be bounded on a interval, but at the same time not attain the maximum and minimum?” and my example explains how that is possible. **Of course** that there is no continuous example.

Comment: Occasionally, "Accepting Does Not Mean Correct" ; **It may still be correct, but I am not sure**, hence Discussing with you. This Q is saying "**Continuous Bounded function** must attain maximum and minimum; Why not ?" This A is saying "**DisContinuous Bounded function** need not attain maximum and minimum; Here is the Example !" ; There is something not adding up !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137338/discussion-between-anotheruser-and-prem).